# Content Page and Master Page events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have had this problem for a while now and no matter what i cannot seem to resolve it.  I have a master page and a content page.

The content page simply contains a button

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

The master page simply contains the content place holders.  The button1 one event fires normally, however as soon as a form is added to the master page the button stops firing.  the master page looks something like this

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
```

## Member Login

```
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="bt_login" 
                        onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</form>
```

Can some one please help, the button works fine without the form in teh master page, however i need a form in the master page

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after running the exact same project on another machine, everything worked fine.  So I'm guessing there is an issue with the way i installed visual studio and asp.net.